# How to add restriction on each duplicated field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each, keyup

I'm trying to add restrictions on every duplicated field I add using jquery. The outcome should be that each duplicated field should restrict the user from entering more than 5 words per field.

This is the code I have so far. Anyone who can help? I'll appreciate it guys. Thank you!

```
$('.itextarea').each( function(){
    $(this).on('keyup', function() {
        var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;

        if (words > 5) {
          var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 5).join(' ');

          $(this).val(trimmed + ' ');
          $('p.help').empty().append('You can only add 5 words per field.');
        }else{
          $('p.help').empty();
        }

    });
});
```

UPDATE: Sorry, here's the html for those who were asking for it.

```
<textarea class="itextarea form-control" name="id_desc[]" aria-required="true"></textarea>
```

Comment: Add also your html

Answer (score 0):

When you want to share the same functionality on elements created by other scripts you can access them by using `$('body').on( events, selectors, callback)`:

```js
$('#add-field').on('click', function() {

  $('#banner-message').append(`<input class="itextarea" />`);

})

// This is how you should access dynamically added elements
$('body').on('keyup', '.itextarea', function() {
  var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;

  if (words > 5) {
    var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 5).join(' ');

    $(this).val(trimmed + ' ');
    $('p.help').empty().append('You can only add 5 words per field.');
  } else {
    $('p.help').empty();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <button type="button" id='add-field'>
  Add New Field
  </button>
  <input class="itextarea" />
</div>
```

Comment: Will try this one on my code. Thanks @darklightcode :) I'll let you know if it works on me

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!! I'm not able to upvote this comment but just letting everyone know this worked. :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/sx9qyL7d/1/) for you. As mentioned by @darklightcode you should use such selector `$('body').on( events, selectors, callback)`, but also you need to bind input event instead of keydown and also you need an additional check duplicated texarea fields. Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you @dganenco for putting the effort to add a fiddle. But I needed all fields to get restricted to 5 words. Your first field doesn't apply it.

Comment: anyway, i've accepted @darklightcode 's comment as a solution to my problem. :)